# Transforming XSD Import for WSDL in Spring WS

Tags: import, xsd, wsdl, transform, spring-ws

I'm tring to extend the example in chapter 5 of the Spring WS guide.  I'm using Spring WS 1.5.9 .

I've added ...

```
<import namespace="http://myco.com/schemas/promotion/v1_2"
    schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/ordersService/Promotion_1_2.xsd" /> ...
```

But spring doesn't appear to be transforming the location of the import like it does for the port.  So on my company website it still shows "localhost:8080"

I have the WSDL generation defined as such

```
<bean id="orders" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition">
    <property name="schema" ref="schema" />
    <property name="portTypeName" value="Orders" />
    <property name="locationUri" value="http://localhost:8080/ordersService/" />
```

Does/Can Spring Framework transform the imports some way ???

UPDATE:  Some more background....

We use the same XSD with the maven JaxB2 plugin to build our response schema objects.  That all works great, and we use the Catalog resolver to actually find the addional business domain XSDs in an included JAR file.  We have 100's of XSDs that describe our business domain.

SO i'm trying not to break that.

What I would like to see is a more detailed example.  An example where JaxB2 is used and XSD -> WSDL functionality.

Should I refactor the XSDs ?
Should I use a WSDL and not an XSD
How do I properly idenitfy the XSDs to spring ?
Do I use "classpath:My_file.xsd" ?  Will I have to list possibly 100's of XSDs to schemaCollection ?

The spring Docs are great but I would like a practical example that matches.

Comment: Spring WS 2 is out, you should really be using that now.

Comment: Some day.  This is existing development I'm trying to whip into shape, so I can move to 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to add detail on the solution we ended up with.  We have been moving to Spring WS 2x.  Here's an updated link...

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html#server-automatic-wsdl-exposure

The trick / key was in that section it says... "If you want to use multiple schemas, either by includes or imports, you will want to put Commons XMLSchema"

So that was the final answer to add that to our project.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.schema</groupId>
     <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
     <version>1.4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Now spring enables additional functionality to allow classpath resolution to work.

Comment: +1 Something similar fixed it for me, I added org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core v2.0.2

Comment: I also had to add `commonsXsdSchemaCollection.setInline(true);` when using java configurations.

Answer (score 2):

Spring-WS can automagically inline all schema elements directly into the WSDL, so that they appear as a single document. This avoids the problem of inaccessible `<import>` URLs.

See [the section](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/server.html#server-automatic-wsdl-exposure) of the Spring WS manual which talks about `CommonsXsdSchemaCollection`.